# Removing null from a value list

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query :

```
<cfif topic NEQ "">
    <cfquery name="queryTopicName" datasource="#ODBC#">
        select topic as topicName from ltbTopics where topicId in (#topic#)
    </cfquery>
    <cfset selectedRiskCategories = ValueList(queryTopicName.topicName)>
</cfif>
```

Here the "#topic#" contains  a list  whose first value is empty, so it comes likes **,,51,52,** etc so it gives an error as:

> "Incorrect syntax near ','

. 
The error occurred on line 33", can any one help me in this how to resolve this?

Comment: You mention a null. Is this list coming from another query? If it is and if you are only using that query to retrieve values for this one, then you could just include it in the other select topic as topicName from ltbTopics where topicId in (select topic from some_other_table where something = something_else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.But a simple hack is convert the list to an array and then back to list.

```
<cfif topic NEQ "">
 <cfset arrayTopic = ListToArray(topic)>
 <cfset topic = ArrayToList(arrayTopic)>
 <!---you may need some more validations as it is possible that original list only has commas in it--->
   <cfquery name="queryTopicName" datasource="#ODBC#">
      select topic as topicName from ltbTopics where topicId in (#topic#)
   </cfquery>
   <cfset selectedRiskCategories = ValueList(queryTopicName.topicName)>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for posting the suggestion, can you please elaborate how to implement it in the above code?

Comment: Use `cfqueryparam` in your queries for sql injection prevention and avoiding execution plan regeneration.

Comment: Hey is there any way using query param? Can you suggest, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, i am trying to do from cf query param method, can you please suggest where I am going wrong?<cfif topic NEQ "">
 <cfquery name="queryTopicName" datasource="#ODBC#">
  select 
   topic as topicName
  from 
   ltbTopics 
  where 
   topicId in 
   (
    <cfqueryparam
    value = "#topic#,0"
       cfsqltype= "CF_SQL_INTEGER"
    list="yes"
   />)
 </cfquery>
 <cfset selectedRiskCategories = ValueList(queryTopicName.topicName)>
</cfif>

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for your answers the final query that worked for me
perfectly is:

```
    <!--- Query to extract selected risk category filters --->
<cfif topic NEQ "">
    <cfset arrayTopic = ListToArray(topic)>
    <cfset topic = ArrayToList(arrayTopic)>
    
    <cfquery name="queryTopicName" datasource="#ODBC#">
        select 
            topic as topicName
        from 
            ltbTopics 
        where 
            topicId in 
            (
                <cfqueryparam
                value = "#topic#"
                cfsqltype= "CF_SQL_INTEGER"
                list = "true"
            />)
    </cfquery>
    <cfset selectedRiskCategories = ValueList(queryTopicName.topicName)>
</cfif>
```

Once again thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I recommending looping and testing for integers or use the justNumericList UDF (preferred) http://cflib.org/udf/justNumericList  This is especially important if the "topic" value is either a FORM or URL parameter.  Beware of non-integer numeric values (scientific notation, long, decimal, a number followed by a space, etc).  `<CFIF ListLen(justNumericList(Topic))> <cfqueryparam value="#justNumericList(Topic)#" list="yes" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER"> </cfif>`